# Android Beginner Insights

Tags: java, android, database

So I'm starting an android project, very new to it and to java.
But I have a knowledge in programming, especially VB.

I'm planning to create and app for certain users to see the data from a database. Is it possible without an internet connection? If not, will be a difficult task?

Comment: why don't you look up for some tutorials? Here one of the first google results for "android database tutorial" - http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: If you have the database on your phone locally you do not need internet connection. Otherwise of course you need an internet connection.

Comment: this link help you to connect your app to server using data connection http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: big thanks guys! this is a nice start. sorry for asking for a broad question. i will work now for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the database? Is it online? When you say "Data Connection" do you mean Edge/4G/LTE or WiFi or Bluetooth? Your device has to connect at least once to the database in order to copy over the required data, and it depends on the database, but you might as well just copy it locally all over to the device itself.

Here are few starting points:

- [Internet](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)
- [WiFi](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm)
- [Bluetooth](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-quick-look-bluetoothadapter--mobile-7813)
- [Database (SQL)](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

I also recommend getting [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356565) book for beginners (try Google-ing it, you know...) . It was very helpful for me to use it. In about a week (if you are fast like that) you can have a pretty solid experience and understanding.